# Windows 10 'Reset this PC' good for removing all malware or is there a better method to fully reset a laptop?

Tags: windows, bios, malware, system-restore, reset

Resetting my Windows laptop with the inbuilt factory reset seems to be a simple task which will bring it back to a blank slate with just Windows installed - as if I just brought the device from the store. I believe that this could remove some malware if there was any on my device. However, I am wondering what this will do to more advanced malware such as the ones that go on BIOS and latch onto firmware. Is there an easy way to "factory reset" to a blank Windows state (after I create a system image and back it up using macrium reflect to another device) in order to use this laptop again from scratch and remove any possibility of malware? Thanks!

Comment: Whether it would clean it or not [which I doubt] you can't copy an image back afterwards or you just re-import what you thought you'd got rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only malware I know of that can survive a Windows Reset is a root kit virus.

Check for root kit viruses with TDSS Killer (Kaspersky).

Otherwise, a full Windows Reset will work for you to start fresh.

Do not Keep Data when you refresh. Use the Keep Nothing option.  Keep Data keeps your Windows Profile which, then, is not a full reset.

To your point about making an image and bringing it back is not useful as that will just bring back problems. You need to go the full Reset facility in Windows.